# Following SMS sent by Twilio REST API and managing the answer

Tags: c#, twilio

I am currently trying to make a notification system using the C# Twilio REST API which will be sending SMS to various numbers. However, these SMS will have a question included.  The answer message needs information from the original message to make the association between the two.

How is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to create an enumeration that represents the questions(ie:'what's your name?' = 6), and then in a database store the enumeration you last sent each phone number? I've worked with SMS services before and trying to parse metadata from one does not sound efficient.

Comment: @KyleGoode I`ve considered the reply and we'll be rethinking our message flow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Kyle is spot on.  As long as you are just sending one question at a time, rather than relying on meta-data in the SMS message, in your application just keep track of what question you just sent to a specific phone number and then if they have replied to it.

Hope that helps.